# convert javascript function into angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use bellow javascript function in custome directive my angularjs app. How to i convert thi javascript function into angularjs custome directive?

I have use demo [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)

```
function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#navPills li').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#navPills ul li').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
}
```

**Edit:**

I have tried this,

```
app.directive('scrollSpy', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var offset = parseInt(attr.scrollOffset, 10)
        if(!offset) offset = 10;
         var scrollPos = offset;
        $('#navPills li').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('#navPills ul li').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

and its displaying error `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: post a working fiddle if possible

Comment: i have edit question and mention fiddle and what i have tried. @IProblemFactory

Comment: why you want to make a directive? An what are you try to reach? Do you want an ttribute for the top element? Or something for the div in your page?